# How to show the full title in the mission control?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, monterey, mission-control, trim

I'm new to the macOS, one thing that I noticed when using mission control is that when the window title gets too long, it'll get trimmed, it's especially confusing when there're multiple similar windows open. I tried hovering over the title, but the full text won't show up, is there any way to show the full title?

[image]

Comment: So do something like 21-project.doc instead of project-21.doc

Comment: @SolarMike So there's no way to show the full description?